# Remove WP 6.4 Lightbox "Expand on Click" functionality

Tags: block-editor, lightbox

I've been using a standalone lightbox plugin for quite some time and it's worked excellently for many years. Now, since WP 6.4 released its own lightbox functionality, it's not working properly on new pages/posts. I have no need for Gutenberg's new default lightbox and want to remove it entirely to see if this resolves the issue.

I have tried updating the theme.json file to include the following ([based on what's in the WordPress documentation on lightbox](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/global-settings-and-styles/settings/lightbox/)):

```
{
  "settings": {
    "blocks": {
      "core/image": {
        "lightbox": {
          "allowEditing": false,
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Despite this in place, the lightbox toggle is still available in the back end and the Gutenberg lightbox is still functional.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: `theme.json` is cached for performance reasons, did you clear all caches? This is also assuming that `theme.json` is valid JSON, I notice there is no `version` field in what you included so it must only be a partial/example `theme.json` in your question not the entire JSON, without a version field set to 2 WP will assume you want the legacy version 1 and this newer option probably won't be parsed or used as a result ( https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/global-settings-and-styles/introduction-to-theme-json/#adding-a-version )